# How to set the readTimeoutMillis parameter in CassandraConnectorConf

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I'm trying to configure the Spark CassandraConnectorConf by applying the SparkConf, as in the code below. However, I found that the readTimeoutMillis is set to default all the time. How can I set it to another value?

```
CassandraConnector connector = CassandraConnector.apply(sc.getConf());
```

Comment: what are the versions of spark / cassandra lib? do you use spark-cassandra-connector from datastax?

Comment: Spark 2.0.2. Yes, I'm using spark-cassandra-connector from datastax